# How to use fread() to read 2 integers in a line?

Tags: c, fread

I need to read 2 integers in a line and somehow store them to compute the distance between two coordinates.

These codes will be provided in binary.

```
3
122 188
222 288
322 388
```

3 is the number of coordinates there is in a file.

(122) is x coor and (188) is y coor.

So far from what I'm getting

```
FILE* fp = fopen(argv[1], "rb");

int points;
long numbytesread=0;

numbytesread= fread(&points, sizeof(int), 1, fp);
```

Comment: What trouble are you having?

Comment: your binary data probably does not have line break into it

Comment: The first code block *isn't* what the file actually looks like, right?

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding the concept of how to read and store 2 seperate integers in a line?

Comment: @immibis i don't think so. It'll be in binary.

Comment: also, how do i store the number in an array?

Comment: It's either in binary or in lines. I can't imagine a sensible binary format that uses the concept of lines.

Comment: umm that was the professor's way of visualizing it to us. I think i'm not getting something right here. SO, when we use fread(),  how does it read a file?? for example if earlier I transform the above numbers to a binary file, will fread() reads and store individual numbers without considering '\n' and spaces?

Comment: Show the output of `xxd file`.  If you have a binary format, there should be no spaces or newlines.  If there are spaces and newlines, they will not be ignored by fread.

Comment: check out the man page for `fread` http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fwrite.3.html. basically this function reads `n` (in your example 1) chunks of size `s` (in your example `sizeof(int)`)

Comment: You *could* use `fread`, but you'd be better off with `fgets` + `sscanf`. Is this some homework assignment with restrictions? Also your example isn't binary. Rather than `122 188` do you mean it will contain `7a20bc0a`? 7a being 122, bc being 188, 20 being a space and 0a being a newline.

Comment: @QMallow does the answer i provided work for you? if not please clarify what you need.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a binary format, You will probably end up creating a data structure (either a `struct` or a simple array of some type) that will hold the binary contents represented by a line in your example.

Assuming for right now that the format is simply integers next to each other in memory, the following program should work.

```
#include <stdio.h>  // printf
#include <stdlib.h> // malloc
#include <stdint.h> // standard int sizes (eg: int16_t, 16bit integer)

typedef int16_t coordinate[2]; // just two integers, but convenient

int main(int argc, char ** argv){
    FILE * fp = fopen(argv[1], "rb");
    int16_t number_of_coordinates = 0;

    // read number of coordinates into our variable
    fread(&number_of_coordinates, sizeof(int16_t), 1, fp);
    printf("%d\n", number_of_coordinates);

    // allocate space for our coordinates;
    coordinate * coordinates = malloc(sizeof(coordinate) * number_of_coordinates);

    // read all the coordinates at once
    fread(coordinates, sizeof(coordinate), number_of_coordinates, fp);

    // print them out just to prove it worked
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < number_of_coordinates; i++){
        printf("%d %d\n", coordinates[i][0], coordinates[i][1]);
    }

    free(coordinates); // always free what you malloc
    fclose(fp);        // always close what you open
}
```

**EDIT** I updated the code to fix some syntax errors. This should now work.

Comment: `int` isn't a fixed size, it is *at least* 16 bits. OTOH the size of the fields in the file is fixed. So reading `sizeof(coordinate)` might read 4 bytes, it might read 8, it might read 16. It would be safer to use a [fixed width integer type from `stdint.h`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types#Fixed-width_integer_types) for `coordinate`. The OP didn't specify what the size is, but I'm guessing `int16_t`.

Comment: Hi, can you explain a bit more? I'm not really understanding what you're doing with coordinate * coordinate and malloc.

Comment: `coordinate * coordinate` is  an array of coordinates. `malloc` is used to get memory allocated for that array.

Comment: @QMallow, in this case array just means a bunch of `coordinate`s next to each other in memory. and since `coorditate` is just two integers next to each other in memory, it really just says read in 3 groups of 2 groups of 16bits, treating each 16bit as an integer